# Reading Character in to the program

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am newbie! I am stuck here. Not sure why the code doesn't work. Any help from here??

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Enter the first letter of the color ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        char color = scan.next();

        switch(color){
            case 'r': 
                    System.out.println("Red");
                    break;

            case 'g': 
                    System.out.println("Green");
                    break;

            case 'b': 
                    System.out.println("Blue");
                    break;

            case 'w': 
                    System.out.println("White");
                    break;

            default: 
                    System.out.println("NO Color");
                    break;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the code does not work?

Comment: Just to let you know: Every time you format code like that, god kills a kitten :(

Comment: Second time I've seen you post the kitten comment in a few minutes. While funny, it's nit-picking...

Comment: What's bad about the formatting of his code?

Comment: @Steve - I took it as a friendly tip to a new user ie "Help us to help you. Please format your code properly."

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't use java too much, but if I had to venture a guess:

```
char color = scanner.next();
```

Is incorrect. The `next()` function returns a string, not a char. So, you could have this:

```
char color = scanner.next().charAt(0); // get the first char in the string
```

Or you could make `color` a String:

```
String color = scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
char color = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

`scan.next()` returns a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

scan.next() returns a string. a quick fix would be to get the first char from it, like :
 scan.next().charAt(0);